# How to enable syntax highlighting for *.handlebars files within Netbeans 8

Tags: netbeans, syntax-highlighting, handlebars.js

Perhaps this question might be silly, but I need some help. I did the upgrade from Netbeans 7.1 to Netbeans 8, in order to get more functionality and I'm involved in a project that uses handlebars. The problem is I can not find a way to highlight this file. I've tried to go to tools-> options-> Miscellaneous->file and change the file extension and file type associated with no results.

Can you help me with this issue or give me other alternatives that support web editor handlebars?

thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I followed this link and applied the HTML mime type and worked fine.

This are the instructions from the webpage:

```
Go to Netbeans -> Preferences -> Miscellaneous -> Files on a Mac
or Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Files on Windows

Leave "File Extensions" as "< Choose the extension >" and click the "New" button.

Type in the extension without the dot.

Select the appropriate file type from the "Associated file type (MIME)" drop down box.
```

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/netbeans-syntax-highlighting-file-extensions/

Comment: I don't see the appropriate file type from the "Associated file type (MIME)" drop down box. That is, "text/x-handlebars-template". Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps Netbeans latest version has changed since this answer was from 2014